# parent page properties magnolia

Tags: nodes, jcr, magnolia

when i'm creating a new page i want to get a parent page property. I create a custom combofield with nodes from a specific path, but i need a parent page property to complete my path. Any idea?

```
session = MgnlContext.getJCRSession(myWorkspace)
foundNode = session.getNode("/"+ parentPageProperty);
NodeIterator childrenIterator = foundNode.getNodes();
Iterable<Node> childrenIterable = NodeUtil.asIterable(childrenIterator);
List<Node> allNodes = NodeUtil.asList(childrenIterable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to reach to the root node, if that's the case you can do the following:

```
Node rootNode = session.getRootNode();
rootNode.getProperty("ofChoice");
```

Cheers,

Comment: thanks, but i dont want the rootnode, i want the parent node, thanks anyway

Comment: then you can do session.getNode("nodePath").getParent();

Comment: i know that, but i'm want know parent node where i am in dialog, creating the new node

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it, can you elaborate it further ? I understood that you want to get a parent node of something but it shall be parent node of what ?

Comment: when i create a new node, i want to check the parent's properties

Comment: If you are talking about creating a new page, you will hit to info.magnolia.pages.app.action.CreatePageAction. There you see JcrNodeAdapter. With that object you can do the following:                    Node createdNode = itemChanged.getJcrItem();
                    Node parentNode = createdNode.getParent();
                    PropertyIterator parentNodeProperties = parentNode.getProperties();